# Retrofit2 + RxJava + Jackson fails silently

Tags: java, jackson, rx-java, retrofit2

I am investigating a Java 8 REST client setup, using Retrofit2 and RxJava. When using a `GsonConverterFactory` erverything works as expected. When switching to a `JacksonConverterFactory`, I don't see any result at all (but no exception either). According to the log, the REST call itself is OK.

Full example on [GitHub](https://github.com/netzwerg/retrofit-rxjava-jackson/blob/2a8910ff7e38f7ab6370d376d3aa700f15869b0a/src/main/java/ch/netzwerg/retrofit/GitHubClientDemo.java).

Comment: Did you check the error event in TestSubscriber?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrofit's `JacksonConverterFactory` does NOT ignore unknown properties by default (in contrast to e.g. Feign's `JacksonDecoder`).

It is thus necessary to configure a custom `ObjectMapper` with the `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` feature set to `false`:

```
ObjectMapper jacksonMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(jacksonMapper))
        .build();
```

Comment: i'm having the same problem. But even spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false isn't working for me. any idea ?